# How to extract hostname from $(who am i)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, strings

I try to extract the hostname from the following string (created using `who am i`):

```
username pts/0        2010-10-05 17:30 (www.example.com)
```

I need a solution which also works if (www.example.com) is not present which is the case when I am logged in locally. Furthermore the solution also has to work on a Mac where `who am i` returns the following string:

```
username ttys006      Oct  5 16:47 (www.example.com)
```

The problem is that the mac puts spaces in the date which makes it hard to use `cut`. I think, there must be a solution using `sed` to extract the substring, but I have problems figuring out how to use `sed` appropriately.

**Update:** Mad's approach

This approach only works well if there are actually parentheses present. If not, the following happens:

```
$ who am i | cut -f2 -d '(' | tr -d ')'
username ttys006      Oct  5 16:47
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is where `awk` is the best tool.  `awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}'` should pull out what's in parenthesis.  Prints nothing if it's not there. So...

`$ who am i | awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}'`
`www.example.com`


--Christopher Karel

Comment: Do you really need a signature in your answer?

Comment: @Chris  Why not?  I put them on E-Mails, forum posts, etc.  It's a habit, and the space usage is negligible.

Comment: Do you put your signature/tagline twice in forums/blogs/emails/etc.  See http://serverfault.com/faq specifically, "Can I use a signature or tagline?"

Comment: As a matter of fact, Chris, yes.  All those methods already have user information included in the post via account details/source E-Mail address/etc.  Consider it a personal touch analogous to signing a document, despite the letter head and envelope containing far more information about yourself.  The FAQ entry is new to me, and duly noted.  But I'll probably keep signing my posts, until a significant number of people complain.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `who am i | grep -o -e "\((.*)\)"` on both systems, and it simply returns an empty string if you're logged in locally.

Comment: Another pretty neat solution, I have to say. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you like cut (and I'm not saying there aren't more elegant ways to do it, but you chose the tool, and I rather like cut, too), try

```
who am i | cut -f2 -d\( | tr -d ')'
```

You take the second field, using left-paren as the separator (whcih will include the closing paren, though not the opening one), and then use tr to delete the close-paren.

I'm not sure about the case when the string isn't present, as all the times I try it on a locally logged-on machine I get *something* returned in the brackets.  Could you give an example of what you get under those circumstances?

Comment: Thanks for trying. This was one of my first attempts, too. It doesn't work though (see updated question).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sed` version which works with or without parentheses around the hostname or spaces in the date:

```
who am i | sed 's/.* (\?\([^)]*\))\?$/\1/'
```